# Magento 2.0 admin menu not working

Tags: authentication, admin, magento2

I have install magento 2.0

> when i have logged in at admin panel,all admin menu links are
>   disabled and none of them is working.

Can some one help me, where i have commit a mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have find the simple solution:
Open the file di.xml at the location:

```
app/etc/di.xml
```

For version Magento 2.3.1 
Go to line number 714 line:

Older line:

> Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink

Replace it with (New line)

> Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\copy

There is no need to remove any file in any directory.This solution works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Open up app/etc/di.xml find the path “Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink” and replace to “Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy”

for more details refer : http://www.dckap.com/blog/magento-2-admin-links-not-working-in-windows/

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1.**

```
$ php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

**Step 2.**

```
$ php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

[If magento2 url’s or admin url is not working ?](http://gotechnies.com/magento2-urls-admin-url-working/)

Answer (score 2):

Had this same issue on a production site and did the following to alleviate the problem:

**Step 1.**
Deleted the static folder using `rm -R static/*`

**Step 2.**
Cleared cache `php bin/magento cache:clean` & `php bin/magento cache:flush`

**Step 3.**
Reran compile `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

**Step 4.**
Generated static content `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

**Step 5.**
Changed permissions to 777 for pub/static folder `chmod 777 -R . /static`

Followed those steps and my admin backend loaded fine.

Answer (score 1):

I just did the following:

- cd magento2 folder
- run shell command

My System:

- magento 2.0.2
- xampp 7.0.3
- windows 7

```
Justin@GATEWAY f:\xampp\htdocs\mag2
# php -f bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete the files under pub/static to get rid of any existing symlinks. You may want to be careful not to delete the .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

I have found a simple solution:

Open the file `app/etc/di.xml`

Go to line 707.

Replace the line:

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink
```

with

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\copy
```

There is no need to remove any file in any directory. This solution works for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove everything, except .htaccess file from pub/static folder
2. Open up app/etc/di.xml find the path

   “Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink” and replace to 
    “Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy”